# Onclick & On/Off Class Script Not Working on Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, firefox

I have a page with two iframes and a simple navagtion bar. Clicking links in the nav bar targets one of the iframes on the page and replaces it's content.  I'm trying to hilight the currently selected link in the iframe, and it seems to only work on Firefox.  Can you guys offer any advice? Thanks.

Can be seen in full at [www.serioussportstv.net/bigbrother.php](http://www.serioussportstv.net/bigbrother.php)

In the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function offclass(id)
{document.getElementById(id).className = 'class_off';}
function onclass(id)
{document.getElementById(id).className = 'class_on';}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#links a.class_on {
color:red;
}
a.class_off {
color:white;
}
```

Navigation Bar Links (for each link):

```
<a id="link1" class="class_off" href="/streams/bb/live2.php" target="player"        style="font-size:16;font-family:Arial;text-decoration:none;" onclick="onclass('link1'); offclass('link2'); offclass('link3'); offclass('link4'); offclass('link5'); offclass('link6'); offclass('link7');">Show</a>
```

Comment: You have 2 `link6` id's -> `<a id="link6" class="class_off" href="/streams/bb/5.php" ...>Camera 5</a>
<a id="link6" class="class_off" href="/streams/bb/q.php" ...>Quad</a>`, so `offclass('link7');`/`onclass('link7');` will cause an error.

Comment: Thanks very much Jatin.  I've fixed that error however it still does not resolve the issue of the code not working in Chrome/IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try toggle class. Something like this should suffice:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){  $("#link1").click(function(){    $("a").toggleClass("class_on");  }); }); </script>
```

Goodluck, hope this works for you.

You can see the method in use here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_toggleclass